# Process Builder Issue

Tags: java, process, builder

I am working on a java program where I have to call another java program using process builder because it uses a separate JRE.

Here is batch program which calls this program and works properly:

```
cd C:\apps\Project_name\bin\
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.6.0_03\bin\java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
     -cp ../lib/spring-1.2.2.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar;../lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;../lib/wrapper.jar
     com.project.main.MainProgramLauncher arg1 arg2
```

Now I declared my code something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "java",
    "-Xms512m",
    "-Xmx1024m",
    "-cp ../lib/spring-1.2.2.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar;"+
    "../lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;../lib/wrapper.jar",
    "com.project.main.MainProgramLauncher arg1 arg2 ...argN"
);
Map<String, String> environment = builder.environment();

environment.put("path", ";"); // Clearing the path variable;
environment.put("path", java_bin_location+";");
Process javap = builder.start();
InputStreamReader tempReader = new InputStreamReader(
    new BufferedInputStream(javap.getInputStream())
);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tempReader);
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

But its not executing the way it should be. The program crashing right away. Is there anything different I should be doing? Please suggest.

Comment: (I've broken some of the lines whilst formatting, which should make it easier to see what is going on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you should make your class name and parameters different strings. instead of:

```
"java",
"-Xms512m",
"-Xmx1024m",
"-cp ../lib/spring-1.2.2.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar;"+
"../lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;../lib/wrapper.jar",
"com.project.main.MainProgramLauncher arg1 arg2 ...argN"
```

It should be

```
"java",
"-Xms512m",
"-Xmx1024m",
"-cp",
"../lib/spring-1.2.2.jar;../lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar;"+
"../lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;../lib/wrapper.jar",
"com.project.main.MainProgramLauncher",
"arg1",
"arg2",
...
"argN"
```

The other noticeable thing that you used the full path name to call `java.exe`, but not when you used `ProcessBuilder`.

You might also want to read the error stream (or call `redirectErrorStream(true)` - the argument is important(!)).